# Why await is making my for loop very slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I am implementing a chatbot using nodejs and messages are not sending in order that's why I changed **sendMessage()** function and created promise but when I call sendMessage function using await keyword why this is making for loop very slow?

I also want to insert data into sql. Please help me

> > sendMessage Function

```
let sendMessage = (sender_psid, response) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
        // Construct the message body
        try{
            let request_body = {
                "recipient": {
                    "id": sender_psid
                },
                "message": {
                    "text": response
                }
            }
            // Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
            request({
                "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages",
                "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
                "method": "POST",
                "json": request_body
            }, (err, res, body) => {
                // console.log(body)
                if (!err) {
                    resolve('Message Sent');
                    console.log('message sent!')
                }
                else {
                    reject("Unable to send Message "+err)
                    console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
                }
            });
        } catch (e){
            reject (e);
        }
    });
};
```

> > **handleMessage Function**

```
let handleMessage = async(sender_psid, received_message) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedMembers.length; i++) {

                    let memberDetail = selectedMembers[i].split(",");
                    memberID = memberDetail[0];
                    memberName = memberDetail[1];

                    console.log(memberID);

                    // Query to insert values in Info table
                    query = "INSERT INTO info (task_id,task_desc,member_id,member_name,assigner_id,assigner_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    values = [taskID, taskDescription, memberID, memberName, assignerID, assignerName];

                    // Query Execution
                    conn.query(query, values, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log("Member ID " + memberID + "Member Name " + memberName + "Inseted into info table");
                    });

                    await sendMessage(memberID, assignerName + " has assigned you a task.");
                    console.log(taskDescription);
                    await sendMessage(memberID, taskDescription);
                }
                sendMessage(assignerID, "Task Assigned Successfully to " + selectedMembers.length + " members.");
            }
}
```

Comment: Your loop will be blocked from continuing until your `await` call to ""https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages" is resolved.

Comment: @GeorgiB.Nikolov So sir, How can I send messages very fastly?

Comment: You can drop the `await` before your `sendMessage` call. They will be sent asynchronously and will be no-blocking. I suggest you read more on [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)

Comment: @GeorgiB.Nikolov But it breaks the order of messages

Comment: But it makes sense that it does. You need to wait all of the fetches to be resolved to receive all of your values in correct order. Each call blocks the previous one, resulting in your slow code

Comment: You can refactor it to be asynchronous and non blocking, but this will require lengthy explanation of asynchronous Javascript, which is out of scope for a StackOverflow answer. I can guide you to the `Promise.all()` method, which is what you need.